# remove newline and whitespace parse XML with python Xpath

Tags: python, xml, xpath, newline

Here is the xml file http://www.diveintopython3.net/examples/feed.xml

My code is 
[image]

My result is [image]

My questions are

1. how to remove the `\n` and the following white space in the text
2. how to get the node whose text is "dive into mark", how to search the text syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `normalize-space(.)` on each node.

```
import lxml.etree as et

xml = et.parse("feed.xml")
ns = {"ns": 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}
for n in xml.xpath("//ns:category", namespaces=ns):
    t  = n.xpath("./../ns:summary", namespaces=ns)[0]
    print(t.xpath("normalize-space(.)"))
```

Output:

```
Putting an entire chapter on one page sounds bloated, but consider this &mdash; my longest chapter so far would be 75 printed pages, and it loads in under 5 seconds&hellip; On dialup.
Putting an entire chapter on one page sounds bloated, but consider this &mdash; my longest chapter so far would be 75 printed pages, and it loads in under 5 seconds&hellip; On dialup.
Putting an entire chapter on one page sounds bloated, but consider this &mdash; my longest chapter so far would be 75 printed pages, and it loads in under 5 seconds&hellip; On dialup.
The accessibility orthodoxy does not permit people to question the value of features that are rarely useful and rarely used.
These notes will eventually become part of a tech talk on video encoding.
These notes will eventually become part of a tech talk on video encoding.
These notes will eventually become part of a tech talk on video encoding.
These notes will eventually become part of a tech talk on video encoding.
These notes will eventually become part of a tech talk on video encoding.
These notes will eventually become part of a tech talk on video encoding.
These notes will eventually become part of a tech talk on video encoding.
These notes will eventually become part of a tech talk on video encoding.
```

All your newlines have been removed and multiple spaces replaced with a single space.

Part two of your question is asking for the *title* tag as that is the only tag with the text you are looking for, but to specifically find the title with that exact text, that is simply:

```
xml.xpath("//ns:title[text()='dive into mark']", namespaces=ns)
```

If you wanted any node that contained the text, you would just replace *ns:title* with a wildcard:

```
xml.xpath("//*[text()='dive into mark']", namespaces=ns)
```